# Sensu check for MySQL long running Queries.

Tags: mysql, bash, sensu

I need to build a test / checker ( ruby, python, bash , your personal pref) that will check for long running queries every few minutes. It will incorporate with sensu, and then alarm if the threshold is met. Sensu will be able to alarm ( or I can set up custom slack notifications )

Honestly I am not even sure where to start. I am really looking for how you guys would approach this issue.  any help would be great!

I can provide a sample of what I used to test other things on the DB if that would help.

Answer (score -1):

You could execute the following queries in the context of your checker to activate the slow query log and read the name of the file that logs the slow query contents:

1. Activate the slow query log file:

`set global log_slow_queries = 'ON';`

2. Get the path to the slow query file:

`show global variables like '%slow_query_log_file%'`

You can then monitor the file for slow queries.